# How to delete table row using jButton from another jFrame?

Tags: java

I am currently using FileWriter to write data into .txt tile. 
Once I double click the row in the table, it links to another jFrame. 
I wanted to set a button at the particular jFrame so that it is able to delete the row in the table. How can I perform the action?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Table, are you talking about a `JTable` or …? Agree to @UweAllner’s comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **MVC** (Model-View-Controller) paradigm.

Have a *controller* class, maybe containing the `main` method.

That holds the *views* (`JFrame`) and the data *models* (i.e. a `DefaultTableModel`).

That table model is passed to the table, which actually is also a listener to changes of the table model.

On button press let the button tell the controller that a row should be deleted.
This is done on the table model, and change events are fired. Automatically when using a `DefaultTableModel`. Or do it manually when using an `AbstractTableModel`.

MVC is not necessarily more direct, but there are not calls from one component to another components littered through the sources. It decouples things.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding a New button. Go into the codding of the button and add a simple sql statement saying to drop a row from the table And the another statement to show the table again by Select * from tablename;